# Rational coefficients of the prime roots of unity (basis set in $\mathbb{Q}$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots, cyclotomic-fields

It is well known that the set of prime roots of unity $S = \{\zeta, \zeta^2, \zeta^3, ..., \zeta^{p-1}\}$ form a basis in $\mathbb{Q}$ (where $\zeta = e^{\frac {i2\pi}{p}}$, $p \in \mathbb{N}, p $ is prime) 
i.e., 
$$X = a_1\zeta + a_2\zeta^2 + ... + a_{p-1}\zeta^{p-1} $$ is unique for $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I want to ask the following:

> Given $X \in \mathbb{Q}[\zeta]$, is it possible to find the $a_i$ $(\in \mathbb{Q})$, such that 
>   $$X = a_1\zeta + a_2\zeta^2 + ... + a_{p-1}\zeta^{p-1} $$

Comment: You need the trace function to calculate the coefficients. It is easy to show that $tr(\zeta_p^j)=-1$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,p-1$. Trivially $tr(1)=p-1$. Therefore we have the formula
$$a_j=-\dfrac{tr(X\zeta_p^{-j})}{p-1}.$$
Don't know if this is neither what you wanted nor very helpful in practice :-(

Comment: How is this $X$ given to you, if not as a polynomial in $\zeta$?

Comment: As the value of the polynomial. My question is that if I am given an $X$ which is obtained by some starting set of $a_i$, is it possible to retrieve the set of $a_i$ which produced $X$.

It is guaranteed that every $X$ will have a unique set of $a_i$ producing it, but how does one compute them?

Comment: I'm not quite certain that I follow. What do you mean by "value of the polynomial"? Do you mean you're given $X$ as a complex number in the regular $a+bi$ form for real $a, b$? Then how are $a$ and $b$ given to you so that you can know _exactly_ what they are?

Comment: If you're given the value as $a+bi$ with real $a$ and $b$ given as decimals, you're out of luck, since (for most $p$) these polynomials are dense in the complex numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm slightly new to this, so I don't understand why you cannot find $a_i$. There is an injection from {$a_i$} to $X$, so there should be a way to find the $a_i$ from $X$, right?

Comment: @2vrk1504 In theory, yes. If you know the _exact_ value of $X$ in some form, there should be a way. But what way this is will depend entirely on _how_ you know the exact value of $X$. And if you only know an approximate value of $X$ (no matter how good an approximation it is), then there is most likely no way whatsoever of recovering the $a_i$. With that in mind, how exactly is this $X$ given to you? Do you have an example?

Comment: Here's a much simpler question to illustrate the problem. The real number $3.78547563100928546733\dots$ has a unique expression as $a+b\sqrt2$ with $a,b$ rational. Find them.

Comment: What if there is a stricter constraint on $a_i$, like $a_i \in Q \subset \mathbb{Q}$ and $|Q|$ is finite?

Comment: Again, it's going to depend on _how you know what $X$ is_ (and also in this case on how close to one another the values of $Q$ are). So, again, how _exactly_ is this $X$ given to you? Could you give us an example to illustrate?

Comment: $X$ is given in $a + ib$ form. 

For example,
Let $a_i \in Q = \{0, 1\}$ and $p = 5$.
If $X =  -0.80901699437... + i 0.58778525229...$, then $a_1 = 0, a_2=1, a_3=0$ and $a_4=0$.

Comment: If you're given $X$ as $a+bi$ where $a$ and $b$ are given as decimals (like in your example), then I think brute force trial and error is the best way. Maybe some clever tricks (which I suspect are basically unique to each specific case) might rule out some options for you, but that's about it I fear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments explain, there is no "exact" way to do this. However, using the LLL algorithm, one can certainly "guess" what the answer may be, and then (in your particular context) check the answer. Here is a short pari program which, for a given prime $N$, first chooses a "random" vector $[a_i]$ of length $N-1$ with integer entries between $1$ and $1000$, and then $X$ is the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_i \zeta^i$. Then it looks for a linear relationship with small coefficients between the powers $X$ from $0$ to $N-1$.

To "check" the answer, it checks whether the number field defined by this polynomial embeds into the appropriate cyclotomic field. It then lists the random vector it started with and the "guesses" produced by the program (since it doesn't differentiate between the conjugates of $X$ it will give the conjugates as well). It is written in pari/gp (apologies for the hackiness)

```
\p  1000;
N=5;
z=exp(2*Pi*I/N);
R=vector(N-1,k,random(1000));
X=sum(k=1,N-1,R[k]*z^k);
V=vector(N,k,X^(k-1));
L=lindep(V);
nf=nfinit(sum(k=0,N-1,L[k+1]*t^k));
nfc=nfinit(polcyclo(N,t));
Y=nfisincl(nf,nfc);
Z=t*lift(Mod(Y/t,polcyclo(N,t)));
R
Z
```

a random example output:

```
%11 = [726, 983, 378, 318]
? Z
%12 = [983*t^4 + 318*t^3 + 726*t^2 + 378*t, 318*t^4 + 378*t^3 + 983*t^2 + 726*t, 726*t^4 + 983*t^3 + 378*t^2 + 318*t, 378*t^4 + 726*t^3 + 318*t^2 + 983*t]
?
```

Comment: Do you know the order of complexity of `nfisincl` function?